# Python: Semantic error in Hex Conversion Code Function

Tags: python, function

I have written a function for my 4 hexit hexadecimal to decimal converter, and while it works, there is a semantic error I can't figure out. Could you please tell me what the error is?

```
def convert16_10(hexa):
    den = 0
    for i in range(4):
        if hexa[i] == "A":
            den += (16 ** 3-i) * 10
        elif hexa[i] == "B":
            den += (16 ** 3-i) *11
        elif hexa[i] == "C":
            den += (16 ** 3-i) * 12
        elif hexa[i] == "D":
            den += (16 ** 3-i) * 13
        elif hexa[i] == "E":
            den += (16 ** 3-i) * 14
        elif hexa[i] == "F":
            den += (16 ** 3-i) * 15
        elif hexa[i] not in "ABCDEF":
            den += (16 ** 3-i) * i
    return den
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Don't you think this looks way too complex for what it should do?

Comment: When given a hex number it gives a number much bigger e.g. when the answer should be 13107 it says 24562

Answer (score 0):

you can simple convert it with this code:

```
i = int(hexa, 16)
```

Comment: You mean `det = int(hexa, 16)`?

Answer (score 0):

- You should use parentheses in the power in `(16 ** 3-i)`. Should be `(16 ** (3-i))`.
- You should multiply the digit after converting it to an integer instead of the index in `* i`. Should be `* int(hexa[i])`.

Solution:

```
def convert16_10(hexa):
    den = 0
    for i in range(4):
        if hexa[i] == "A":
            den += (16 ** (3-i)) * 10
        elif hexa[i] == "B":
            den += (16 ** (3-i)) *11
        elif hexa[i] == "C":
            den += (16 ** (3-i)) * 12
        elif hexa[i] == "D":
            den += (16 ** (3-i)) * 13
        elif hexa[i] == "E":
            den += (16 ** (3-i)) * 14
        elif hexa[i] == "F":
            den += (16 ** (3-i)) * 15
        elif hexa[i] not in "ABCDEF":
            den += (16 ** (3-i)) * int(hexa[i])
    return den

print(convert16_10("007F")) # => 127
```

Comment: @RC Glad that helped :).